# Можно ли обособить приложение с помощью тире или нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

О техническом регулировании в Российской Федерации и роли Минпромторга  рассказал N.N. — Директор Департамента государственной политики в области технического регулирования и обеспечения единства измерений  Министерства промышленности и торговли Российской Федерации.

Answer (score 1):

Приложение относящиеся к имени собственному обычно обособляется запятой. Приложение может отделятся тире в следующих случаях:

а) если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слово "а именно" например: В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно  -  огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни;
 б) перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность или дается разъяснение такого приложения, например: Я не слишком люблю это дерево - осину;
 г) для внесения ясности, если приложение относится к одному из однородных членов предложения, например: За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра - подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых лиц, моя жена и я. 
 д) для отделения препозитивных (стоящих впереди) однородных приложений от определяемого слова, например: Автор замечательных произведений для детей, блестящий переводчик, поэт и драматург - Маршак занял видное место в русской литературе;

***Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. Розенталь Д.Э.***

Ваш случай не подпадает под эти пункты.

**Обновление**

[[@Alenka](/users/4012/alenka)](/users/4012/alenka), тире обычно носит разъясняющий, конкретизирующей характер. В вашем случае нет такого оттенка. В вашем примере приложение, стоящее в конце предложения, сообщает лишь дополнительную информацию о существительном, выраженном именем собственном. Оно не поясняет его. Ср.: Наконец появился и механик — молодой парень, еще не снявший институтского значка. Здесь приложение содержат в себе развернутую характеристику предмета или лица.

Comment: Но ведь мое приложение как раз находится в конце предложения, и думала, что здесь этот случай...

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Типичный случай. Ставится запятая. И да, не вполне понятно, отчего директор вдруг стал Директором.

Ваш случай не подходит под (д) из ответа [@Серж](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6) потому, что после N.N не содержится повествования, а есть лишь определение наподобие *"Так нам сказал Кастро, президент Кубы"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
В то время я знал только, что в Симбирске жил Гончаров – медлительный человек, владевший почти сказочным даром русского языка (Паустовский).

Здесь определяемые слова – собственное имя лица. Приложения уточняют его качественную характеристику.
```